# Arch Linux kernel panics and firmware not working

Tags: boot, archlinux, firmware, kernel

Before the update I had `linux-raspberrypi-3.1.9-33-arm` and `raspberrypi-firmware-20120418-2` installed. After I upgraded to `raspberrypi-firmware-20120729-1`, the kernel refused to boot (no kernel panics or messages) but start.elf started.

Copying start.elf from `raspberrypi-firmware-20120418-2` (old firmware) causes it to boot, but then the kernel panics.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing : Attempted to kill init
PANIC:Attempted to kill init!
```

Removing all the USB devices it managed to boot into a **crippled state**.

cmdline.txt

```
smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 loglevel=2 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

Why won't the new firmware work at all?

**EDIT:**
All of the firmware packages in the [mirrors](http://us.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/arm/alarm/) are useless except for the [old image](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv6/raspberry-pi)

Comment: Can you give a dump of the whole boot log? That error message means that something quite serious has happened.

Comment: Did you check the md5/sha1-sum of your downloaded image?

Comment: @Joost: He's only upgraded the firmware on a working image.

Comment: @Jivings Can't seem to find /var/log/messages.

Comment: So none of the firmware packages worked for you? I haven't had a problem on my system.

Comment: @Jivings Nothing works except the ones from the official Arch Linux Arm image.

Comment: @Jivings Could you post your all your configuration files in your `/boot`?

Comment: I have just been updating the firmware using pacman from the alarm repository. Have you been using `rpi-update`? Perhaps that would result in different, non-Arch specific files.

Comment: @Jivings I used pacman as noted by the package info.

Comment: @Haskeller Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and should be closed because it is has received no attention (aside from edits) since April of 2013. No answer has been provided and this question would most likely carry limited usefulness now.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness This is a legitmate question, though.  It's not unclear and it is definitely pi specific because it involves a firmware issue.  I suspect it might be "too broad" (because there is not enough information to say one thing definitively) but I am not sure.

Comment: @goldilocks That makes sense.